# Include JavaScript file in another Javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript file in which I need to create an instance of a javascript class found in a different js file. Is there any way I can just "include" or "require" the file in which the Class is found? I read about using Ajax or creating a separate function to load the file, is there a more simple way?

I read here [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) but I'm looking for something simple, as the project is too small, if I use any of these, the code for including the file will be longer than the actual code needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: I read that :( I just wished I have not understood it and there is an easier way ...

Comment: you also could load the required js file before the other in your html document - definitions of methods and objects are saved in the browser after loading the script and you can access them globally (if the scope was global in your js file)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Assume 2 have 2 js file:

> file1.js

```
var MyClass = function() {
    // some code
    return something;
}
module.exports = MyClass;
```

> file2.js

```
var MyClass = require('./file1.js');
// use MyClass
```

This code above run correctly when run on nodejs server.

Comment: Don't you have to define 'require' somewhere?

Comment: 'require' is a funtion in javascript, you don't have to define it.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I can see it here http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/ Thanks!